# ACF Taxonomy only returning child - want both parent and child

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following function:

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
{
global $post;
global $current_user;
$field['choices'] = array();
wp_reset_query();
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'gear',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,

      ));
    
        foreach($query->posts as $product_id=>$macthed_product){
            $zz = get_field('brand_preselect',$macthed_product->ID);
            $yy = get_field('category_tax',$macthed_product->ID);
            $aa = get_field('weight',$macthed_product->ID);

            foreach( $yy as $term ): 
                $choices[$macthed_product->ID] = '<u class="cat">' . $term->name . '</u>' . '<i class="brand">' . $zz . '</i>' . $macthed_product->post_title . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(' . $aa . ' kg)';
            endforeach;
                
        }

$field['choices'] = array();
if( is_array($choices) )
{
        foreach( $choices as $key=>$choice )
    {
        
        $field['choices'][$key] = $choice;
        
    }
}
 // wp_reset_query();
return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=choices', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

This works well in that it populates the checkboxes with the category name, brand and title. For some reason $term->name in the foreach only shows the child category. If I echo out $term->name before the $choices[$macthed_product->ID] it shows all that apply. How do I get $term->name in the foreach to show all taxonomy matches (parent and child)

Comment: You are simply _overwriting_ `$choices[$macthed_product->ID]` in each loop iteration, so of course only the last value “survives” after that.

Comment: @CBroe ok -  so how would i solve this issue?

Comment: Add new array elements instead? `$choices[$macthed_product->ID][] = …` But then the following part will probably also need modification.